# How to lazy-load a very large library (Reveal BI)

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I have an Angular 11 application where I want to use a library called [RevealBI](https://www.revealbi.io/), which is quite large (16MiB!!!). So instead of eagerly-loading it, I want to lazy-load it when a certain page is visited.

Lazy-loading works while testing with `ng serve` but it's failing when trying to `ng build` because, I guess, Angular's CLI is trying to optimize it.

How can I tell Angular';s CLI to not try to optimize or do other work on this library's chunk?

This is the lazy-loading code:

```js
import("./reveal-deps")
    .then(() => {
        // Use RevealBI here
    });
```

And that `reveal-deps.ts` file contains:

```js
import "dayjs/dayjs.min";
import "quill/dist/quill.min";
import "reveal/infragistics.reveal-1.0.4.js";

export default { };
```

In my `angular.json` I have:

```json
"configurations": {
  "dev": {
    "optimization": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "buildOptimizer": false 
  }
}
```

And the error I'm getting with `ng build` is, after 30 minutes of trying to build (which usually takes 5 minutes):
[image]

The log file mentioned in there has this:
[image]

If I change to `"sourceMap": false` then the code can be compiled, and I see these 2 chunks being generated:
[image]

But because I still want sourcemaps for my own scripts, I can't turn it off.

Answer (score 1):

The workaround we ended up doing is to append a `script` tag dynamically to the `body` when Reveal needs to be loaded, like this:

In `reveal-deps.ts`:

```js
// Reveal is loaded asynchronously by adding a "script" tag to the body. This code wraps the `<script onload=...>`
// callback into a promise so the rest of our code can know when Reveal has finished loading.
const revealLoadedPromise = new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
    const script: HTMLScriptElement = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "assets/reveal/infragistics.reveal-1.5.0.js";
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.onload = () => resolve();
    script.onerror = error => {
        log.error("An error occurred while loading/executing Reveal's main script", error);
        reject(error);
    };
    document.body.appendChild(script);
});

export { revealLoadedPromise };
```

And in the code that needs to use RevealBI:

```js
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        import("./reveal-deps")
            .then(result => result.revealLoadedPromise)
            .then(() => this.setupReveal())
            .catch(...);
    }
```

This way the library is only downloaded when it's needed.

## Another workaround

To by-pass completely Angular's CLI lazy-loading and do it manually by attaching this to the `body` tag at runtime when a certain page is reached:

```
<script src="assets/dayjs/dayjs.min.js">
<script src="assets/quill/dist/quill.min.js">
<script src="assets/reveal/infragistics.reveal-1.0.4.js">
```

Comment: Updated answer with a better alternative than the original one.